# Метод для получения названия html-страницы

Tags: java

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу. Написать метод для получения названия произвольной html-страницы. Например, `httpTitle("http://www.google.com.ua")="Google"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В HTML есть такая штука, как тег `<title>`:

```
<head><title>java - метод для получения названия html страницы - ХэшКод</title></head>
```

Всё, что вам нужно - это достать исходный код страницы и найти там значение этого тега.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду Метод getHost

Comment: Понятия не имею о каком getHost() вы говорите. Я описал вам единственно верный, общий алгоритм, состоящий из пары простых шагов - я верю, что вы в силах реализовать эти шаги на Java (или на любом другом языке). А если не в силах - то задавайте более конкретные вопросы по ходу (только перед этим крайне рекомендую поискать нужную информацию в поисковиках).